# foreach not looping all data

Tags: php, database, laravel

my first query that gets all rows that contain both the user who requested friendship ( authenticated user id ) and inbound friendship ( inbound user id ). This works if I echo $rowsget, it echos the correct rows, the problem I'm having is that it will only loop through up to two usernames, once I take away the ability for it to loop through the profiles own username it will only loop through one row then stop, I have tried what some people have said to do but it now says this error message when I try to load the profile page, "Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int" Here is the code, any help is appreciated, I have been stuck on this for hours now.

**Query**

```
$rowsget = DB::table('friends')->where(function(Builder $query) use($uid) {
    $query->where('requesteeid', $uid)
        ->orWhere('inboundid', $uid);
})
->where('approved', true)
->get();

$rowfetchfriend = [];
if(count($rowsget) > 0){
    foreach($rowsget as $get) {
        $getrequestee = $get->requesteeid;
        $getinbound = $get->inboundid;
        $rowfetchfriend += DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)- 
>orWhere('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);
}
```

**Loop through usernames**

```
foreach($rowfetchfriend as $loop) {
        if($loop->id != $uid) { //make sure own user isnt displayed
            echo $loop->username; // echo all usernames that are
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method (or the push() method) when adding to an array:

Instead of this:

```
$rowfetchfriend += DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)->orWhere('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);
```

Try this:

```
$rowfetchfriend[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);
$rowfetchfriend[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);
```

The class and its methods are listed here:
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_count

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am still getting this error, Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int . I can change the $rowfetchfriend from += to = although this fixes the error message I still have the issue with the loop & I was chatting with someone prior and they said this is the correct thing to do, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I see, then there might be another issue. Instead of $rowfetchfriend +=, try doing $rowfetchfriend[] =. Notice the brackets.

Comment: Im getting this error message, Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: You probably got several results on this line: $rowfetchfriend += DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)- 
>orWhere('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);

Comment: So when you loop over it later, your variable $loop is sometimes a collection. You should either make your query more distinct and fetch only one record at a time, or you should check if it's a collection, using if($loop instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Collection).

Comment: Just tried that, it now displays no users?, I wanted it to loop through all profiles whether there is a collection or not, is this possible? thanks

Comment: I would split it into two different queries. $rowfetchfriend[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']); $rowfetchfriend[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);

Comment: Don't do the instanceof check if you're using this solution. That was just an example of how you could check if you got several results or not.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this $rowfetchfriend[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);
$rowfetchfriend[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']); and also without the [] at the start if i dont use the brackets the page loads with no results, if i use the brackets i get this error message, Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Did you also remove the earlier query for $rowfetchfriend?

Comment: Code gets messy in the comments, so I edited my answer above to make it more clear.

Comment: Yep, I did that, I did the way you mentioned with the $rowfetchfriend = []; then removed that and the [] from the database query when I take the [] away the page shows no results when I add them I got the Property[id] error message above. would you have any other suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use "push" method of laravel collection.

try this :

```
$rowfetchfriend = [];
    if(count($rowsget) > 0) {
        foreach($rowsget as $get) {
            $getrequestee = $get->requesteeid;
            $getinbound = $get->inboundid;
            $temp = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)->orWhere('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);
            array_push($rowfetchfriend, $temp->toArray());
        }
    }
```

and Loop through usernames :

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($rowfetchfriend); $i++) {
        if($rowfetchfriend[$i][0]->id != $uid) { //make sure own user isnt displayed
            echo $rowfetchfriend[$i][0]->username; // echo all usernames that are
        }
    }
```

I tested it and work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added the $rowfetchfriend = []; at the top of the if count statement because it wouldn't recognize the variable and now it's giving this error message, Call to a member function push() on array

Comment: I edit my code. Try it. I think it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's half working for me, some accounts cannot see their friends, some profiles show all friends and some show only the first friend? would you know why? thanks

Comment: Maybe it's from your DB structure or it's relationship.
You can debug it step by step to find the problem.
First of all, use dd() method to see what datas return for each profile. If it is same as the datas that you mention, the problem is from your db structure or your db query.

Comment: I've spent hours on this, when i dump the results its the same as if i were echoing :(

Comment: If you're sure that you have more data, update your question and put this two table structure to help you